# The GridView fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, page-index-changed

i have allowed paging and added the below codes but got the error. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Code:

```
  protected void SubmitAppraisalGrid_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        SubmitAppraisalGrid.PageIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;
        SubmitAppraisalGrid.DataBind();

    }
```

Design:

```
<asp:GridView ID="SubmitAppraisalGrid" runat="server" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderWidth="0px" 
                onrowcreated="SubmitAppraisalGrid_RowCreated" ShowHeader="False" 
                style="margin-right: 0px" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="1" 
                onselectedindexchanging="SubmitAppraisalGrid_SelectedIndexChanging">
               </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 13):

> **If you have set a gridviews AllowPaging attribute to “true” and do not handle the `PageIndexChanging` event then this error raise.**

To work with paging add the `PageIndexChanging` event handler to grid and change your markup and code as:

```
<asp:GridView ID="SubmitAppraisalGrid" runat="server" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderWidth="0px" 
                onrowcreated="SubmitAppraisalGrid_RowCreated" ShowHeader="False" 
                style="margin-right: 0px" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="1" 
                onselectedindexchanging="SubmitAppraisalGrid_SelectedIndexChanging"
                OnPageIndexChanging="SubmitAppraisalGrid_PageIndexChanging">
               </asp:GridView>
```

///

```
protected void gvList_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    SubmitAppraisalGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    SubmitAppraisalGrid.DataBind();

    //bindGrid(); 
    //SubmitAppraisalGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    //SubmitAppraisalGrid.DataBind();
}

protected void SubmitAppraisalGrid_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
   /// you selected index related logic here.
}
```

This event is not raised when you programmatically set the [PageIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindex.aspx) property. 
Check MSDN documentation of [GridView.PageIndexChanging Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindexchanging.aspx)

For reference:
[The GridView fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled](http://forums.asp.net/t/1021805.aspx/1)

Comment: +1 for letting us know about AllowPaging attribute. If this is is set to "true" can also cause the issue without the PageIndexChanging event.

Answer (score 11):

Your code should be inside On **PageIndexChanging** Event

```
  protected void SubmitAppraisalGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        SubmitAppraisalGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        SubmitAppraisalGrid.DataBind();
    }
```

Design:

```
<asp:GridView ID="SubmitAppraisalGrid" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderWidth="0px" 
            onrowcreated="SubmitAppraisalGrid_RowCreated" ShowHeader="False" 
            style="margin-right: 0px" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="1" 
            OnPageIndexChanging="SubmitAppraisalGrid_PageIndexChanging">
           </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
OnPageIndexChanging="SubmitAppraisalGrid_PageIndexChanging"
```

instead of

```
onselectedindexchanging="SubmitAppraisalGrid_SelectedIndexChanging"


protected void SubmitAppraisalGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    SubmitAppraisalGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGrid();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

insted of using

```
SubmitAppraisalGrid.PageIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;
```

you must use

```
SubmitAppraisalGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
```

and if you got error again plese post the error too..

Answer (score 0):

Step by Step:

1. Select gridview from design and go to property and fire the event (PageIndexChanging)
2. Code : `gridviewname.pageindex=e.NewPageIndex;`

Comment: Please read other answers. Yours doesn't seem to add something new to them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the Pageindex changing event from selected index changing event of dropdown.

```
protected void PageDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Retrieve the pager row.
    GridViewRow pagerRow = SubmitAppraisalGrid.BottomPagerRow;

    // Retrieve the PageDropDownList DropDownList from the bottom pager row.
    DropDownList pageList = (DropDownList)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("PageDropDownList");

    // Set the PageIndex property to display that page selected by the user.
    GridViewPageEventArgs evt = new GridViewPageEventArgs(pageList.SelectedIndex);
    SubmitAppraisalGrid_PageIndexChanging(sender, evt);
}
```